# Get the Class name and Method Name at any Location in Java /Android

Tags: java, android

I am android developer and love logging very much. I had been using a convention for my logs that is in form of

> [ClassName:methodName()]

Whenever i have to log something, this help me find exact location from where a specific log is generated and helpful in many cases.

Instead of writing each time the

> ClassName

and

> MethodName

manually i wrote a method. Their may be better approach of doing this. Any answer without using loop is **Accepted**.

```
public static String getRef(Object object) {
        StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        String method = "";
        if (elements.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].getClassName().equals(object.getClass().getCanonicalName())) {
                    method = elements[i].getMethodName();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return "[" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + "::" + method + "()]";
    }
```

Calling:

> Log.d(STRING_TAG , GlobalConfig.getRef(this) + " Server
>   Response:"+json);

i had already tried using

> Object.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();

but its always returning me null and also it is supposed to return the method name where it is called right? as the documentation says

> If this Class object represents a local or anonymous class within a
>   method, returns a Method object representing the immediately enclosing
>   method of the underlying class. Returns null otherwise. In particular,
>   this method returns null if the underlying class is a local or
>   anonymous class immediately enclosed by a type declaration, instance
>   initializer or static initializer.
>   
> **Return**
>  Method the immediately enclosing method of the underlying
>   class, if that class is a local or anonymous class; otherwise null.

Comment: Use *slf4j* and *log4j* there you can simply configure the outpus as you like, no need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks for your feedback, actually android does have its own Logging Library, all i want is to get the method name at any point in application.

Comment: *" android does have its own Logging Library"* - wrong:  https://www.slf4j.org/android/

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks i didn't knew that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you going to call it directly, I explain:

1. You are on class A, and want to log that you are here
2. You will call this method directly from class A

You can use this:

```
 StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
 String method = "";
 method = elements[elements.length - 2].getMethodName();
 return "[" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + "::" + method + "()]";
```

Where you get the last but one class called. Ex:

```
public class Random {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Random r = new Random();
  r.test();
 }

 public void test() {
  System.out.println(Logger.getRef(this));
 }

}

class Logger {

 public static String getRef(Object object) {
  StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
  String method = "";
  method = elements[2].getMethodName();
  return "[" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + "::" + method + "()]";
 }

}
```

> Out: [Random::test()]

Comment: you cannot find the index statically  elements[elements.length - 2]

Comment: Sorry, but, why not? I mean, if you want the caller, it will be that last but one in the array. Even when you call `Log.d(STRING_TAG , GlobalConfig.getRef(this) + " Server Response:"+json);`. That is the only way to get the information you want without looping through all the index and checking by class name

Comment: what if there are other elements in StackTrace, according to your code that is right

Comment: public static Random r;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  r = new Random();
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
 public void run(){
 r.test();
 for(int i=0;i<100;i=i+2){
 //do something
 System.out.println("working:");
 }
 }

 }).start(); 

 }

Comment: Make the above change and then try, you cannot fix the element and its not always the second last one

Comment: using  > Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); you have to loop i was asking about any other method of getting method name espacially

Comment: Try to add it to your own code and see if there is any error...I absolutely sure that it works, it get only the current thread

Comment: I tried it dear, as i said it is ok for what you write not applicable for the situation where you have thread running, and more than one instance are available.

Comment: On thing is for sure that you cannot specify the static value if you want to work it for all cases no a single or few cases.